# You are not authorized to view this page. HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to server configuration

Tags: python, web, python-requests

I am new to python Programming. I am learning website **scraping**. Our office has a server for our employees only. I wanted to **scrape** it. But some ERROR happened and I am unable to get the HTML content.
Here is the code--

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page= requests.get("http://xxxx.aspx")
soup=BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

it gives HTML content which after compilation gives:
[Photo.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnVmn.png)

Comment: When you try to access that page in browser, do you need to login? If so, you also need to login when accessing it through python. What kind of authentication you need to use depends on how security on that server is implemented.

Comment: No, it doesn't require login information. But when I log in to my computer in office, it requires log in ID and password. Actually this site is not accessible outside my office.

Comment: And you run this code from your office pc or?

Comment: Yes sir.........

Comment: Maybe you should ask system admins at your office how to access the site programmatically. As the error says, it's a server side issue which doesn't allow you to access the page...

Comment: okay sir...........

Answer (score 0):

You are not providing any credentials. How website would recognize you? You can try using `mechanise` along with BeautifulSoup. It lets you supply your username and password to access the website.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import mechanise

page = mechanize.Browser()
page.Open("http://xxxx.aspx")
page.form["user"] = "YOUR_USER_NAME"
page.form["password"] = "YOUR_PASSWORD"
```

Comment: let me try tomorrow, then I'll tell you